How can I Customize Antdesign Steps?
Is there any way to Customize antdesign steps line?
I am currently working on a next JS project, and we are using module CSS. So, I am recently stuck on customizing these antdesign steps. I was successful in achieving it using global, but I am still unable to customize the steps line. How can I do that? The antdesign has a default line of blue, but I want green, and it's not working even when I use global.

You can easily customize the Ant Design steps line using the ConfigProvider component, which is available from version 5 of Ant Design. By defining the theme tokens in ConfigProvider, you can apply global styles such as changing the primary color of the steps line.
Here’s a sample code snippet that sets a custom color for the steps line:


import { ConfigProvider, Steps } from "antd";

const CustomSteps = () => {
  return (
    <ConfigProvider
      theme={{
        token: {
          colorPrimary: "#00FF00", // Customize the line color here
        },
      }}
    >
      <Steps
        size="small"
        current={currentStepIndex}
        progressDot
        status="finish"
        items={[
          {
            title: "In Process",
          },
          {
            title: "Evaluation",
          },
          {
            title: "Submission",
          },
        ]}
      />
    </ConfigProvider>
  );
};



